# DataGrip: how to connect to Oracle as SYSDBA

Tags: oracle, sys, datagrip, sysdba

I tried to setup in [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) an Oracle connection under SYS user.

But got error:

> ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER

But there is no option in GUI to choose `as SYSDBA` option.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Coming back here two years later, it seems to be not possible anymore to change the advanced properties in the connection settings.

Instead you have to supply `sys as sysdba` as username. 
(This might seem obvious but took me a while to find this out)

Comment: How did you manage to change the advanced properties?
I couldn't find the `internal_logon` key and was unable to add one.

Comment: I guess, available property names list comes from the driver when it's attached.

Comment: This does not work for me in v2022.1.4, while @Vadzim solution to set `internal_logon` to `sysdba` in Advanced tab worked fine

Answer (score 21):

While there is no easy switch currently, it's still possible to go to Advanced tab in connection's properties and set [`internal_logon`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/urls.htm#CHDJHCFE) param to `sysdba` value.

Comment: Yeah, that's the answer

Comment: Not able to modify the values in that tab (2018.2.3). The `sys as sysdba` solution worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

While this has been answered already. I would like to be a little more descriptive by adding screenshots.

Add a new database. Make sure the username is set to `sys as sysdba`. The default password usually is `oracle`.

[image]

Now moved to `Advanced` tab. Here find `internal_logon` and set it's parameter to `sysdba`.

[image]

That's it. You're ready to connect.

Comment: Off-topic, how did make this screenshots?

Comment: inbuilt in mac. `Command` + `Shift` + `5`.  Then select `Capture Selected Window`. That's it!

Answer (score 7):

`sys as sysdba` as username works fine for Database plugin in IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

> sys as sysdba

As username works fine in Pycharm